# How make Auto linking keywords in text with Php?

Tags: php, str-replace, autolink

Here is my code.My destination was: i will enter some content text(like articles), keywords and site url. And in the end keyword in text will be linked to url i was given for once.
But code doesnt work. So where is my mistakes?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

   <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<div style="float:left">
<table width="40%" border="0" >   
<tr>
    <td height="30" class="yazi">Text</td>
    <td height="30">:</td>
    <td height="30">
    <span class="formyazi"><textarea name="text1" cols="75" rows="25"></textarea><br></span>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width="23%" height="30" class="yazi">Keywords</td>
    <td width="1%" height="30" class="style1">:</td>
    <td width="76%" height="30">
    <span class="formyazi"><input type="text" name="keywords" value=""></span>
     </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width="23%" height="30" class="yazi">site adress</td>
    <td width="1%" height="30" class="style1">:</td>
    <td width="76%" height="30">
    <span class="formyazi">http://<input type="text" name="site" value="">/</span>
     </td>
</tr> 






<tr>
    <td height="55" colspan="3">
        <input type="submit" class="button" style="font-size:10pt;color:#FFFFFF;border-style:solid;border-width:1;background-color:#0D78B3" value="Send!">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
 </form>  


<?php
$text2=$_POST["text1"];
$nesne=str_replace($keywords,'<a href="$link" title="$keywords" target="new">$keywords</a>',$text2 ,1);
$linkedtext=$nesne;
?>   
<div style="float:left">
<table width="40%" border="0" > 
<tr>
    <td height="30" class="yazi">Text with link</td>
    <td height="30">:</td>
    <td height="30">
    <span class="formyazi"><textarea name="cikti" cols="75" rows="25"><?php echo $linkedtext;?></textarea><br></span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to get $keyword from $_POST just  like you did with the "text1" input's value into $text2. Also you're using $link, which isn't ever defined. Maybe you meant $link = $_POST['site'] ? Also you're trying to use $keywords within single quotes, so it will output the string '$keyword' instead of the actual value of the variable.

Comment: yes you are right.i added   `$link=$_POST["site"];
    $keywords=$_POST["keywords"];` but this time i recived this text as output: <a href=".$link." title="$keywords" target="new">.$keywords.</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've gotten the correct $_POST variables according to your comment, you need to fix this now

```
$nesne=str_replace($keywords,'<a href="$link" title="$keywords" target="new">$keywords</a>',$text2 ,1);
```

You cannot put variables in a single-quote delimited string - use double quotes around it with single-quotes inside.

Like this:

```
$nesne=str_replace($keywords,"<a href='$link' title='$keywords' target='new'>$keywords</a>",$text2 ,1);
```

Comment: `$nesne=str_replace($keywords,"<a href='$link' title='$keywords' target='new'>$keywords</a>",$text2 ,1);`
it is work, but not for one time, change all keywords in the text.